# FatalErrorException in helpers.php line 36: Call to undefined function exif_imageType()

Tags: php, laravel, imagen

Buenos días:
Cloné un archivo Laravel y a la portada de la página si la abre, pero a la hora de dar click para ir a la siguiente página me sale lo siguiente:
Call to undefined function exif_imageType()
Si alguien sabe como darle solución a éste problema se lo agradeceré.

Comment: ¿Te has asegurado de que la función `exif_imageType()` existe?

Answer (score 1):

En el manual de PHP está [exif_imagetype](http://php.net/manual/es/function.exif-imagetype.php) (pero todo en minúscula); de donde clonaste el archivo te sugiero buscar la referencia **exif_imageType** así con la T mayúscula y mires si dentro se hace uso de la que mencione o es una nueva implementación.